# how to set this makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I have makefile with two source files namely `main.cpp` and `game.cpp`. Once I add `game.cpp`, I'm getting the following warning

```
clang++ -framework SDL2 main.o -o game
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

And this is the makefile

```
CXX      = clang++
SDL      = -framework SDL2
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -c -std-c++11
LDFLAGS  = $(SDL)
TARGET   = game

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): main.o game.o
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

game.o: game.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm *.o && rm $(TARGET)
```

I'm using Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `game.o` in the build command, this is because `$<` is only the first dependency (see the first line in your warning).
Hence the functions in `game.o` are undefined.

For more info please refer to [gnu.org](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables)

EDIT: Updated the link as suggested

Comment: Why I'm getting `clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-std-c++11'`

Comment: I'd suggest a link to the GNU make manual section on [Automatic Variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html#Automatic-Variables) instead of the link to that random blog post.

Comment: @CroCo I believe, if I remember correctly, that you have to use: `-std=c++11` instead of `-std-c++11`. However, this is only necessary if you use c++11 features.

Comment: @CroCo: Please would you start doing research and reading documentation? The `clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-std-c++11'` problem is very easy to determine yourself by simply looking up the documentation for the arguments.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, would you please stop double check my old posts so that you can find any mistakes. And how do you know I haven't done any research regrading this issue?

Comment: @CroCo: I may look through any posts I choose, with or without your permission. I upvoted a few of yours; you're welcome. (I can tell you didn't do any research because I have a wealth of experience and I know that a trivial Google search would have.... y'know what? Never mind. No point me explaining it since I already did in my previous comment and you chose to ignore it.)